# How to send email on linux with HTML content AND attachment?

Tags: sendmail, mailx

I have Oracle Linux server 7.8, on which I am trying to explore programs which be used for emailing HTML content and also send an attachment. Let say I am in my home directory and i have the following structure

HOME

- ABC (directory which has a file called index.html and folder resources which contain .gif files html)
- ABC.tar.gz (which is a file)

I am trying to send an email using 'mailx' / 'sendmail' programs in such a way that the HTML content is readable and also attach the Index.tar.gz file as well. I tried two options

sendmail

```
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" | cat ~/ABC/index.html | sendmail x.y@z.com
```

It is sending email with html tags

OR

```
cat <<'EOF' - ~/ABC/index.html | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
To: x.y@z.com
Subject: hello
Content-Type: text/html
EOF
```

It is sending email with readable html content (without tags) but is not able to resolve gif images.

mailx

```
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" | cat ~/ABC/index.html | mailx -s "Subject" -a ~/ABC.tar.gz x.y@z.com
```

After executing this option, html content is not coming out correctly but attachment is coming fine.

With mailx or sendmail, how can we send a proper readable html content and attachment as well. I will not be able to use "mutt", so please do not provide that solution.

Comment: you must insert an empty line after `Content-Type: text/html` and before acual html.

Comment: tried the mailx comand after putting echo"", html content is not coming out properly, still contains tags, echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" echo "" | cat , rest of the command after cat remains the same

Comment: I also manage either inline html `cat foo.html | mail  -a 'Content-Type: text/html' ... ` or embeded file `mail --content-name="PNG image data" -A epub-128_cr.png ... `

Comment: this question might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line